# The COM standard marshaler was unable to fix a mismatch

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

On Windows 7 an application install works successfully. The install fails on windows 10

The COM standard marshaler was unable to fix a mismatch between the IID {618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71} provided by the server and the IID {00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} requested by the client, with handler CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. The error code was 0x800401fd.

I tracked the CLSIDs to

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71")]
public interface IAccessible

and

The following GUIDs are used by the OLE Automation Protocol.

Is there some way to debug this issue so that i can see what it is trying to install or register? Or do i just start removing stuff and see what fixes it?

Windows Installer InstallAware is the package creator

I browsed to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\Interface{618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71} on the win 10 machine

it has one key where the value is {03022430-ABC4-11D0-BDE2-00AA001A1953}

Comment: The handler CLSID seems to be wrong. On my Windows 10 box, the CLSID for the handler (reg subkey entry ProxyStubClsid32) is {03022430-ABC4-11D0-BDE2-00AA001A1953} which is PSFactoryBuffer which is in C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll

Comment: The IAccessable interface declaration appears to be missing the [ComImport] attribute.  Which tells the installer to not try to register the interface.  Brr, you'd have to wonder a bit how many Win7 machines got screwed-up by this.   Go back to a Win7 machine were this install was completed, run Regedit.exe and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\Interface\{618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71}.   There must be only one ProxyStubClsid32 key with the value noted by Joseph.